# More than one return in a recursion method

Tags: java, recursion

I created a recursive method which will find the number of occurrences of a specific character`ch` (input by the user) in a text file `file1`
.

the method will receive `file1`,`ch`,`count`the number of occurrences,I put it as argument to avoid resetting it,`x`as file length

```
public static int rec(File file1, char ch, int count, int x) throws IOException {
    char current;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
    current = (char) fis.read();
    if (x == 1 && current == ch) {
        return ++count;          //1
    } else {
        return rec(file1, ch, count, x - 1) + count; //2 
    }
}
```

So the thing is it doesn't return the number of occurrences (it doesn't execute return 2), it just returns `count` from return 1.
How can I fix this ?

edit: I used recursion because this code is part of an assignment which requires solving the problem using iteration  and recursion

Comment: You probably need to pass `fis` to the method, rather than opening a new stream each time.

Comment: If it never executes the recursive call then the condition you're checking for is always true. You should try to see why that is--but consider what character is being read.

Comment: And yes: repeatedly opening an input stream can lead to all kinds of subtle and even catastrophic bugs. It is also not good to use recursion when you can't say how often you make that recursive call. Worst case these could lead to stackoverflow exceptions depending on the content of your file. Seriously: file processing and recursion don't go together nicely.

Comment: I tried passing fis but it didn't work it keeps returning 1

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues:

- you create a new `fis` for every recursive call and therefore ALWAYS check only the first character of the file
- you never check for the end of the file (you do so via the `x` check I imagine...)
- your logic is quite weird and you use too many paramenters
- you use recursion

What follows will be too examples in pseud-code / free text explaining how you could implement it

---

with recursion:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);

public int count(fis, char) {
    read a char
    check if fis is fully read from
    return 0 if fis is empty
    if char matches return 1 + count(fis, char)
    else return count(fis, char)
}
```

---

without recursion:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
while (read char && fis is not empty) { 
    if (char matches) {
        increment count by one
    }
}
```

Comment: Another problem is using Stream instead of Reader to get characters... What if file uses encoding with utf-16 which writes single character on two bytes? Or utf-8 and includes characters which can require even more bytes?

Comment: I check the end of the file by using x ..those param. I need them for the rest of the program..and I use recursion (I edited my q)  ..  in the example you wrote I think the method will recuse infinitely ...thanks for answering

Comment: @JD you are actually correct, I forgot to "return 0" when the stream is empty.

Comment: @JD look at the javadoc of read and see what it returns in case it has reached the end of the file.